# In Python PIL, is there any way to improve the file size of an image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I was asked to improve the file size of an image from 60 kb to around 3 MB. I tried to increase the width and height of the image to get the desired file size. But then I was said increasing the dimensions size decreases the quality of the image so asked me to have the same if not better quality for the image.

How can I achieve this?

Should I increase the dimensions and then use some filters to get improve the quality? Or is there any other way to improve the file size of the image with out changing the dimensions of the image(better quality is fine).

Comment: Simplified: you can't improve the quality (and filesize is not a metric for quality). Either you did misunderstand the task or it's a bad task. The only thing which one could think about is some model-based improvement or super-resolution, but well... There are a lot of strange or wrong statements in your question.

Comment: No!! They have down sampled the images and lost the original images. Now they are left with 80 KB image files. They asked me to increase the file size of the images to 2 MB or 3 MB.

Comment: This isn't a TV show. You can't hit an Enhance button and recover details that an image doesn't contain.

Comment: Hahaha. Well said! I will try to explain the same thing.

Comment: If your source file's dimensions are around 800x800 px (640,000 pixels), you can convert the image to BMP. You will get a file of ~2.5MB

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to increase file size you can increase number of pixels there by increasing width and height of an image. For example, instead of 1 pixel you can use 4 pixel square of same color and you will get increase of file size by 4. So 3MB is about 3 million bytes and 1 color pixel is 24 bits (3 bytes) so you will need about 1000000 pixels. For your case you need 50 times increase so instead of 1 pixel you will need 50 pixels of same color. So increasing width and height by 7 times you will get what you want. However, many pixels should be repeated and image quality will remain the same, so in general it is useless process.

Comment: I think you meant *"1 colour pixel is 24 **bits**"*.  So, that would make the required pixels to be about **1,000,000** to produce a 3MB image.